# On closing Interstitial Ad app move to random activity

Tags: android, admob, android-recyclerview

I created a vocabulary app on which there is a recyclerview which contain the name of the categories and on clicking on each category new activity starts which shows all the words present in that category. In between i placed InterstitialAd, on closing the add it will move to that particular category, But the app moves to some other category. When no ad loaded then right activity starts.

here is the code of the category adapter:

public class AllWordAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

```
private List<AllWordsModel> mCategoryList;
private Context context;
private String fragmentName;

private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

public AllWordAdapter(List<AllWordsModel> mCategoryList, Context context,String fragmentName) {
    this.mCategoryList = mCategoryList;
    this.context = context;
    this.fragmentName = fragmentName;
}

@Override
public AllWordViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.all_words_layout,parent,false);
    return new AllWordViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AllWordViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final AllWordsModel word = mCategoryList.get(position);
    holder.mCategory.setText(word.getmWordCategory());
    holder.mBackgroung.setImageResource(word.getmImageRes());

    if (fragmentName.equals("AllWordsFragment")){
        holder.mStar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }else {
        holder.mStar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    final Activity activity = (Activity)context;

    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(activity);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-9180372532679866/1983137539");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

    holder.mAllWordLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()){
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }else {

                Intent myintent = new Intent(activity, WordListActivity.class);
                myintent.putExtra("Category", word.getmWordCategory());
                myintent.putExtra("Fragment",fragmentName);
                context.startActivity(myintent);

            }
        }
    });

    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener()

                                  {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onAdClosed() {
                                          Intent myintent = new Intent(activity, WordListActivity.class);
                                          myintent.putExtra("Category", word.getmWordCategory());
                                          myintent.putExtra("Fragment",fragmentName);
                                          context.startActivity(myintent);

                                          mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
                                      }
                                  }

    );

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mCategoryList.size();
}
```

}